# Problem with Visual Studio 2005 Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2005, installation, project, solution

My colleague created a Visual Studio 2005 solution for me and I have copied the entire folder in my machine.
The solution contains three different projects. Unfortunately, two of them opens and the third project doesn't with the error message, "The project type isn't supported by this installation". I have installed Visual Studio 2005 with default settings. I don't understand why this would occur.

I tried googling, but none of those worked. I would request the community here to advice me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what type of project is not loading? is it a database project?

Comment: I forgot to mention, it's a ASP .NET Web Service. On a added note, I actually do not get an option to create ASP .NET Web Services under Visual C#, it comes under Visual C++. Has it got something to do with it? If so, whats the remedy.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved. I had to install Service Pack 1.